# Appending ajaxed JSON to existing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LPGeV/

What am I missing here and is there a more elegant way to get at the response data?

```
$.post('/echo/json/',{
    "json": JSON.stringify({
      "rows": [
        {
        "cell1":"row 2 cell 1",
        "cell2":"row 2 cell 2"
        },
        {
        "cell1":"row 3 cell 1",
        "cell2":"row 3 cell 2"
        }        
    ]})
    },
    function(response) {
       $response = JSON.parse(response)
       $response.each(function() { // rows
         var row = '<tr><td>'+$(this).cell1+'</td><td>'+$(this).cell2+'</td></tr>';
         $('#tableID').append(row);
      });                             
    }
);
```

UPDATE: This works:

```
function(response) {
   $.each(response.rows,function() { // rows
       var row = '<tr><td>'+this.cell1+'</td><td>'+this.cell2+'</td></tr>';
       $('#tableID').append(row);
    });                             
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the datatype to 'json' (or use `.getJSON()´, then jQuery will parse the answer for you. (EDIT: Actually jQuery already recognizes the response as JSON and parses for you, so you don't need to parse anyway.)

And since the response data is plain JavaScript objects, it would make sense not the wrap it in jQuery, but use jQuerys "other" `.each()` method:

```
$.post('/echo/json/',{
    dataType: "json",
    "json": JSON.stringify({
      "rows": [
        {
        "cell1":"row 2 cell 1",
        "cell2":"row 2 cell 2"
        },
        {
        "cell1":"row 3 cell 1",
        "cell2":"row 3 cell 2"
        }        
    ]})
    },
    function(response) {
       $.each(response.rows, function() {
         var row = '<tr><td>'+ this.cell1+'</td><td>'+ this.cell2+'</td></tr>';
         $('#tableID > tbody').append(row);
      });                             
    }
);
```

EDIT: And you need to loop over `response.rows` and nor `response`. And Geoff is correct, too.

http://jsfiddle.net/LPGeV/15/

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, the example I looked at was just looping over response, I assumed it would do something like for (o in response) which would be rows. The datatype seems not to matter in Fx at least.

Answer (score 2):

I can't get jsfiddle to load, but you want to append to the tbody, not to the table.

```
$('#tableID > tbody:last').append(row);
```

Comment: I have appended to the table before and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DLaRw/